# Pointless Use of Temporary Tables?

Tags: sql, t-sql, reporting-services, temp-tables

I'm fixing defects on a fairly complex SSRS report that was designed about a year ago. From what I gather, the person who coded the report - a contractor with our organization who is now gone and not available for questions - learned SQL several years ago and didn't keep up-to-date with it - his code is full of outdated and bad practices, such as joining in the WHERE clause, ordering by column numbers instead of column names, and always using temporary tables instead of subqueries or CTEs. Being a newcomer to SQL (less than a year of experience), I always try to figure out the purpose of some of the odd coding I come across and learn the history of any outdated techniques it makes use of. Here's one I haven't been able to figure out - the stored procedures for the report I'm currently working with select everything into temporary tables before making use of the data. If the coder needed two columns on a three-column, 50-row lookup table, he would select those two columns into a temp table first. Even for the final SELECT, he always selects first into a temporary table and then does a SELECT * to access the data. I haven't seen this before, and it seems pointless to me. Why not just access the data directly? Is there or was there ever, in the history of SQL, any purpose in doing this, or is it just plain bad coding?

Comment: Thanks, Gordon and Prahalad. I hadn't considered the reasons you suggested. I think the coder had some sort of misconception about how to code well. Judging from some of the rest of his code, I'm wondering if he had been away from SQL for some time before he coded this report. I'd vote both of your answers up, but I don't have the minimum points needed to do so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will take a guess at this- the reason for use of temporary tables.Please note that the reasonings mentioned below are just some **viewpoints** and may not necessarily be the true reason. It could simply be that the individual did not know the correct way to write SQL. However, here are some reasons a temp table would have been used :

1. Emulating a view - for e.g. him selecting only 2 columns out of 3 columns on a 50 row table, meant that he actually wanted a logical view of the data only within these two columns - something that can be easily accomplished using CTE.
2. Isolating data changes - He wanted to make sure that he is always working on a copy of the data so that he is insulated from data changes to the base table (essentially, this becomes a **snapshot** of the master table) and also did not want to make his queries perform accidental modifications to the base table.
3. Performance - it may be that the original tables that he would query had poorly built indices for search and ordering - and he happened to compensate for this by building temporary tables with the indices built on the columns required within the query and this would help him to achieve faster query processing. It would also provide a way for him to prevent any changes to the master table structure (which would slow down other operations such as inserts and delete).

Having said that, it is important to note that these are all bad coding practices. It is always recommended to use the facilties provided by SQL server such as CTE, Views etc to process data within the database. Temporary tables are good choice when you want to pre-process the data prior to inserting into the table and it is expensive to do so outside of the database (for e.g. imagine a data processing system that reads data from dump files and inserts them into a master table that contains millions of rows. It may be that the dump tables contain duplicate data which is already persisted within the table and hence we do not want to insert such rows. In such a scenario, the data processing system can dump the candidate rows into a temp table and then use the powerful set operations of SQL server in order to filter out duplicate rows.)

Answer (score 1):

From what you describe, I would call this bad coding.

There are a few cases where I could imagine doing a select as you describe.  Most fall into the category of "the table takes a long time to read" or "statistics from the table cannot be used effectively by the optimizer".  One reason could be that the table is in a database on a different server.  Having a local copy often makes the query *much* more efficient.  Or, the "table" could really be a view that takes a long time to process.

One other case would be when there are lots of updates on the table and you want a snapshot for some reason for a series of reports.  You might need consistency between different reports, so putting the data into a temporary table guarantees this.

In general, though, you would never do this.  If you have a small reference table, you would just include it in the `from` clause and access the columns you need.  SQL Server does a good job of optimizing access to the table and of limiting processing only to the columns that are needed.  Putting things in temporary tables hinders the optimizer -- which is generally (but not always) a bad thing.